# Open link using system browser using InAppBrowser

Tags: ionic2, inappbrowser

I am using Ionic 2 and want to open a PDF file from a remote server using the device's default browser. I have a couple of problems:

First, I am unable to run this on the browser. I get this error:

*Native: InAppBrowser is not installed or you are running on a browser. Falling back to window.open.*

The [ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/) seem to indicate support for all devices and browsers. Am I doing something wrong or the docs are wrong?

Secondly, when I run the app, the PDF file does not open in the system's default browser but within the app. I am using Ionic View to do the testing. Here is my code:

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

constructor(public appGlobal: AppGlobal, private iab: InAppBrowser) {

const browser = this.iab.create('www.google.com', '_system');
browser.show();
```

Also, if I change the URL to my php script that generates and returns a PDF file, it does not work at all.

Answer (score 4):

To use the device's default browser, you don't need to use the IAB.  You just need to open a new window with _system.  Your device will do the rest.

```
window.open(url, '_system');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do what you're doing if you want to keep the IPB, just omit the open function.

Adding the _system target means you don't need to do this anymore as it crashes the app.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall inappbrowser plugin and simply try this:

```
window.open(pdf_url, '_system', 'location=yes');
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use _system browser, it's not necessary use browser.show()

```
this.iab.create('www.google.com, '_system');
```